# Store a matrix in 2d char array Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to store a matrix in java 2d char array but since I can't accept the input in char, I am trying to look for the best possible solution to store in a 2d char array.

eg. Matrix

```
 1112
 1912
 1892
 1234
```

What I tried:-

```
 for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            map[i][j]=sc.next().charAt(0);
```

Gives wrong output. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @nileshvirkar , Probably a `Scanner`

Comment: Matrix is always `n*n`? What you mean with *wrong output*?

Comment: try this 
       for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
                for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
                    map[i][j]=sc.next().charAt(j); change charAt(0); to charAt(j);

Comment: @nileshvirkar thats an extremely wrong logic because if I replace it by j, each graph vertice that I accept would require me to input in the form

1,
12,
123,  

since its accepting value at j for each input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the code to

```
String data = "";
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (sc.hasNext()) {
        data = sc.next();
        count = 0;
    } else {
        break;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    map[i][j] = data.charAt(count++);
}
```

for loop of i and j is for generating matrix indexes and since you need to read the character you first have to read token by token then iterate over their characters the other user answer fails because the user uses j loop for both matrix and chracter reading so if on the last iteration of j ie n-1(denotes matrix length not the string length)  if string length is less than n-1 you will get IndexOutOfbound Exception for `in.charAt(j)`.

Comment: Works perfectly but can you explain the logic. I mean its similar to the answer by @sodium24 except the explicit use of count. But the upper one gives an exception while this one prints perfectly. ?